# array() in R is not giving correct dimensions

Tags: arrays, r

I have noticed that when I compute

```
x <- array(dim = c(10000, 10, 1))
```

R does not return an array with 10000 rows as it should. Instead, the command returns only 100 rows.

I have R version 3.4.3 "Kite-Eating-Tree".

Is there any reason why R truncates the number of array rows to 100?

Maybe this has to do with the R version I am currently using...

Any idea what may be going on here?

Any enlightenment is appreciated.

Comment: Work for me `> dim(x); # [1] 10000    10     1`. Note that printing is probably limited and is probably what you're seeing. Is there a warning at the end that some rows have been omitted?

Comment: Nope, no warning about omitted rows... The behaviour I am getting is quite strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Printing is limited to a certain number. By default, you probably have

```
> options("max.print")
$max.print
[1] 1000
```

and 100 rows * 10 columns is 1000. So by that logic, if you limited printing to 20, you would get two rows. Proof:

```
> options(max.print = 20)
> x
, , 1

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
    [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA

options(max.print = 1000) # revert back to default
```

Comment: Thank you! Although R should really give a warning of this IMO.

Comment: Just for clarity,
if you do `data.frame(x)` you Do get a message saying rows were omitted. Not sure why that is indeed not the case for arrays, but I never use `array()` or see others use it much.